# Killing a process

Tags: c#

We have a custom application that was developed for Windows Server 2003 but have issues since migrating this to Windows Server 2008 R2.

Part of the application/process is to kill a Windows process with C# code. This worked fine on Windows 2003, but on Windows 2008 R2 the code fails to kill the process. Has anyone come across anything similar or have any ideas what the issue could be?

Comment: Make sure your code is running under an account that has enough privileges to kill processes.

Comment: "the code fails to kill the process" -- what happens? Nothing? Do you receive an exception? Which one? What's the exact error message?

Comment: Thanks for your comments.

The account is local admin on the box. When this fails, an error is written to the event log:

Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7600.16385, time stamp: 0x4a5bdfe0
Exception code: 0xe053534f
Fault offset: 0x000000000000aa7d
Faulting process id: 0x%9
Faulting application start time: 0x%10
Faulting application path: %11
Faulting module path: %12
Report Id: %13

The process remains in memory. Not sure if that helps.

Many thanks.

Comment: So you don't receive an exception in your C# program, is that right? Can you show us your code?

Comment: That is not a .net exception, there is probably some other event log entries that are more helpfull.  When .net apps cause low level ketnal type exceptions like that it usually means that the .net runtime has fallen over. Have you deubugged the application, if not then that is your next step. Once you have can you post the code that fails, indicate what line it fails on and what happens, does it thow an exception or what.

Comment: Many thanks for your reponses, the developer who wrote this is hopefully going to look this Friday so I may have more information then.

Thanks again.

Comment: I have an app on Windows 2008 R2 and I am able to kill a process in C#.  It is also a process I created in the same program.   Problem I am having is cannot close() the process.  It throws no error but does not close.

Answer (score 4):

> Exception code: 0xe053534f

Always inspiring when the problem has something to do with this site's name.  Microsoft programmers often pick exception codes that can be decoded to a 3 letter acronym.  The exception code for a C++ exception is 0xe04d5343, the last 3 hex bytes decode to "MSC", Microsoft C++.  The exception code for a managed exception is 0xe0434f4d, "COM+" which was the early name for .NET

Give your exception the same treatment and you'll get "SSO".  Which means "soft stack overflow".  That is the exact same thing as a regular stack overflow, except that the system can predict it up front.  It knows that, if it completes the call, the program will bomb because there is not enough stack space left.

Exactly why your app is bombing on a stack overflow isn't clear from the info you provided.  You'll have to debug it.