# How can i figure out KERNELBASE.dll Error?

Tags: c#

I am getting following error from my windows application. the Exception i couldn't figure out why it is coming because the particular error is not log in my Exception Logger file.

```
Application name has failed: Test.exe, Version:1.0.0.15, time stamp: 0x51481394
Failing module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version:6.1.7601.18015, time stamp: 0x50b83b16
exception code :0xe053534f
fault offset :0x0000812f
Process ID has failed:0x% 9
the start time of the applications are failing:0x% 10
Application path has failed :% 11
module path has failed :% 12
Report ID:% 13
```

Please find Below Code

```
private void frmSetTime_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string[] cmds = System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
        //Here i gets Command Line Arguments
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.show(ex.message);
    }
    finally
    {
        GC.Collect();
    }
}

public void ExecuteLogic(Object obj)
{
    try
    {
        //My set of Statements
        Therad.sleep(5000);
        ExecuteLogic(obj);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.show(ex.message);
    }
    finally
    {
        GC.Collect();
        ApplicationRestart();
    }
}

private void ApplicationRestart()
{
    try
    {
        if (Process.GetCurrentProcess().WorkingSet64 >= 10000000)
        {                         
            Application.Restart();                    
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us the code to reproduce the error?

Comment: @Jeremy Thompson Please find the Code Above.

Comment: @RamdasBhosale searching for exception code `0xe053534f` shows that it is due to a stack overflow:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/3406058/161455

Answer (score 2):

You have infinite recursion in `ExecuteLogic` it constantly calls itself.  This will eventually run the system out of stack space.  If you don't want to leave `ExecuteLogic` just use a while loop

Comment: I use recursion in C# to build menus from CRM's. Just ran into this same issue. So a while loop instead of a Lambda expression is better to use ?